# when GC is called in the worker nodes in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm working on a Spark application in which I need to cache RDD in a loop in each iteration. After I'm done with each RDD I try to `unpersist` it. However after a few iteration I keep getting out of memory exception. If the GC is called right after I execute the unpersist, everything should be fine and I should not get out of memory exception (due to the size of my RDD). However, I'm not sure how often the GC is called on the worker nodes. Could someone elaborate that for me?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is related to your case but notice that if you have many iterations the graph of dependencies for your rdds will grow. If this is the case consider using [checkpoints](https://github.com/JerryLead/SparkInternals/blob/master/markdown/english/6-CacheAndCheckpoint.md) which cuts the lineage graph and saves the rdd ( maybe best to do it on every nth iteration ).